# Brunch installed with phoenix app doesn't work with bower assets

Tags: javascript, bower, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have created Phoenix 1.0.4 (Elixir) application. After I had added some logic in application I wanted to switch my work for front-end part. On page http://www.jonathanbirkholz.com/how-to-use-font-awesome-on-phoenix/ I read that for 3rd assets I should use Bower. Unfortunately  with `font-awesome` or `bootstrap-sass` from Bower and with command `brunch build` I always receive:

```
/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1747
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:10)
  at Parser.pp.raise (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1745:13)
  at Parser.pp.unexpected (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2264:8)
  at Parser.pp.semicolon (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2243:59)
  at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2677:8)
  at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2462:160)
  at Parser.pp.parseBlock (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2692:21)
  at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2443:19)
  at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2379:21)
  at Object.parse (/.../my_app/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:101:12)
  at parse (/.../my_app/node_modules/detective/index.js:9:18)
  at Function.exports.find (/.../my_app/node_modules/detective/index.js:44:15)
  at module.exports (/.../my_app/node_modules/detective/index.js:23:20)
  at /.../my_app/node_modules/deppack/index.js:83:12
  at tryToString (fs.js:414:3)
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:401:12)
```

I found that problem is caused by acorn - JavaScript library, so I check dependency tree for Node modules:

```
├─┬ brunch@2.0.4
│ ├─┬ deppack@0.1.5
│ │ └─┬ detective@4.3.1
│ │   ├── acorn@1.2.2
```

Brunch 2.0.4 (The newest released) use dependencies for old acorn library. There are newer acorn versions, but detective library allows to use acorn 1.x.x versions.z

Comment: Here's a post that shows you how to do that http://nithinbekal.com/posts/phoenix-bower/

Comment: @Dikaio thank you for link, but article under this link doesn't tell anything more than link which I pasted. Even article under this link tell less than article under my link.

Comment: @wafcio I think this is more likely to be a javascript issue than it is a Phoenix issue.  I'd add tags for Javascript on your question--may get the right people to look at it to help you.

Comment: added javascript tag and removed elixir. @OnorioCatenacci you are right it is javascript problem, thats why I removed elixir but left phoenix-framework. Phoenix use brunch to compile assets so in phoenix page/chat I should be able to find help with it too.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar and spelling; caps at start of sentences.

Comment: It looks that in Phoenix 1.1.0 I don't see problem with `brunch build`.

Comment: I have this problem with Phoenix 1.1 only when `bower` is in my Gemfile!

Answer (score 2):

Probably I found what was wrong. Bower must be installed globally and shouldn't exist locally (in node_modules).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Try using Node > 5 and NPM 3, clean your cache and install the node_modules again (delete first).

Comment: I am using node v5.3.0 and npm 3.3.12, I was deleting node_modules many times but without positive results.