# Using Bower and Brunch together on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bower, phoenix-framework, brunch

All the examples I've seen online of using the two together rely on Bower being installed globally, but that can't work on Heroku - Bower needs to be a dependency of the app, so listed in `package.json`.

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.0",
    "brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.9.2",
    "bower": "1.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
  }
}
```

And my `bower.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "Kaderi",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "~ 3.3.6"
  }
}
```

However, with `bower` loaded in `package.json`, I always get the following JS error when building assets:

```
./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1747
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:10)
  at Parser.pp.raise (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1745:13)
  at Parser.pp.unexpected (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2264:8)
  at Parser.pp.semicolon (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2243:59)
  at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2677:8)
  at Parser.pp.parseStatement (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2462:160)
  at Parser.pp.parseBlock (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2692:21)
  at Parser.pp.parseStatement (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2443:19)
  at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2379:21)
  at Object.parse (./node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:101:12)
  at parse (./node_modules/detective/index.js:9:18)
  at Function.exports.find (./node_modules/detective/index.js:44:15)
  at module.exports (./node_modules/detective/index.js:23:20)
  at ./node_modules/deppack/index.js:83:12
  at tryToString (fs.js:414:3)
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:401:12)
```

I don't know if this is being caused by Bower itself, or bootstrap-sass/jquery (installed via Bower).

If I use a global install of Bower, the problem does not appear, but my assets cannot be compiled by Brunch on Heroku (due to missing Bower dependencies).

In fact the problem is identical to this [Brunch installed with phoenix app doesn't work with bower assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385107/brunch-installed-with-phoenix-app-doesnt-work-with-bower-assets) and I am also using Phoenix, but for me the problem is not resolved just by upgrading Phoenix (and I don't know how that would affect Bower/Brunch anyway).

What am I missing in this tangled web of JavaScript frameworks?

*edit:* Using nodejs v5.1.1 and npm v3.3.12, both locally and on Heroku.